# rationale for Databricks naming "catalog" and "database" not "database" and "schema"

Tags: databricks

Is there a rationale as to why Databricks calls things Catalog and Database instead of the much-more-standard Database and Schema?

What they call a Database is basically a schema: It can contain tables, views, and functions, but there isn't an additional level beneath it.

What they call a Catalog is therefore basically a Database: It contains individual things (typically called schemas, what they call a database) which contain tables, views, and functions, and which can have their own permissions.

I figure there must be some sort of rationale for their breaking from standard naming conventions, but so far I haven't figured it out. They seem to be an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out why. If you look on [this page](https://docs.databricks.com/en/lakehouse/data-objects.html) in the documentation they say,

> Before the introduction of Unity Catalog, Databricks used a two-tier
> namespace. Catalogs are the third tier in the Unity Catalog
> namespacing model: `catalog_name.database_name.table_name`

In other words catalogs were introduced later, and it used to just be databases containing tables (without the possibility of schemas in between the two), so the naming made sense.

Then they introduced catalogs to contain the two, and I guess they didn't want to rename anything, but are now lightly suggesting that you call databases "schemas".